# Call a function periodically in a cluster of instances?

Tags: asp.net, .net, kubernetes, .net-6.0

In my .NET 6 Kubernetes application (C#, Linux), it needs to call a method every 10 minutes. There are N pods. I have the following option,

1. Set up a distributed lock, e.g. Redis lock. Each instance keeps trying to get the lock every minute. Once it gets the lock, call the function, and release the lock after 10 minutes.
2. Create an API to call the function. Set up a job in a scheduler, e.g. Cron, Windows Task scheduler, or whatever commercial scheduler is available in the company. Let the scheduler call the API periodically.

#1 makes the code base complex. And #2 depends on the external services. Are there any other good options?

Comment: AFAIK kubernetes allows scheduling [Cron jobs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/job/automated-tasks-with-cron-jobs/) you can try it. Depending on the situation you can make a special version of the aforementioned pod which will just call the method. Or you can create a special version of your pod which will have the "calling method" setting enabled and span one instance of it.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by @Guru Stron AFAIK kubernetes allows scheduling [Cron jobs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/job/automated-tasks-with-cron-jobs/) you can try it. Depending on the situation you can make a special version of the aforementioned pod which will just call the method. Or you can create a special version of your pod which will have the "calling method" setting enabled and span one instance of it.

You can use a CronJob to run Jobs on a time-based schedule. These automated jobs run like Cron tasks on a Linux or UNIX system.

Cron jobs are useful for creating periodic and recurring tasks, like running backups or sending emails. Cron jobs can also schedule individual tasks for a specific time, such as if you want to schedule a job for a low activity period.

Cron jobs have limitations and idiosyncrasies. For example, in certain circumstances, a single cron job can create multiple jobs. Therefore, jobs should be idempotent.